# Ordenar por texto después de un espacio

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero hacer una consulta que me deje ordenar después de un espacio.
El nombre y apellido están en la misma columna (en esta ocasión tienen que permanecer así).

[image: ejemplo de nombres y apellidos]

Quiero ordenar de forma ascendente desde el apellido. He probado usando esto, pero no lo he logrado:

```
Select distinct actores,añoLanzamiento
From peliculas
where descripcion like '%shark%' and
descripcion like '%crocodile%' 
Order by actores like '% ' Asc;
```

Comment: Por favor Noslen, si la respuesta que te han proporcionado ha solucionado tu problema deberías marcarla como correcta pulsando en el símbolo **✓** que hay a su izquierda. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [substring_index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index), obteniendo en la última palabra de la columna actores y ordenando por ella, el separador en este caso es un espacio en blanco ' '.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT actores, añoLanzamiento
FROM
    peliculas
WHERE 
    descripcion LIKE '%shark%'
    AND descripcion LIKE '%crocodile%' 
ORDER BY 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(actores, ' ', -1) ASC,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(actores, ' ', 1) ASC
```

Comment: Mi +1. Como mejora te propondría poner como segunda prioridad en la ordenación el campo (o la primera palabra) para que dos apellidos iguales queden ordenados por el nombre.

Comment: Añado tu propuesta a la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda, lo acabo de hacer y salió perfectamente.

Comment: Gracias @Vicent , pero ten cuidado con la coma final. Imagino que la habrás añadido por error al copiar/pegar, provoca un error. Además, corrígeme si me equivoco, pero creo que el parámetro correcto sería `1` y no `0`.

Comment: Cierto, corregido.